# UIComponent.getRouterFor shows TypeScript error: Unsafe return of an 'any' typed value

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, sapui5

I recently added TypeScript to my SAPUI5 project and having problems with the ESLint messages for the types.

Considers this easy example:
[image]

This tiny piece of code shows the error "Unsafe return of an any typed value" but I cannot figure out why.
Everything in this function has a type.
This is the description for UIComponent.getRouterFor from the package @sapui5/ts-types-esm:
[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Are the types correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out, that the linting errors came from the VSCode ESlint Extension.

Since we are using on folder for the CAP project that contains the folders for the CDS development with typescript and also a folder for the app resources, the extension got confused.
There are two .eslintrc.json files. One on the root level(marked with root:true) and one for the typescript UI5 app.

I set the working directories settings of the extension like this

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./app", "./srv", "./db"],
```

and now it works.

Thank you @Peter Muessig for your input.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the UI5 types and ESLint are you using? When I am writing the same code in my `BaseController` then I see another issue: `@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion`

```
public getRouter(this: BaseController) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion
    return UIComponent.getRouterFor(this) as Router;
}
```

which will be auto-fixed to:

```
public getRouter(this: BaseController) {
    return UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
}
```

Due to the type inference there should be no casting necessary.

BTW: In my case I am using ESLint 8.17.0 and OpenUI5 1.102.1.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I cannot access my work right now but we are using the newest SAPUI5 version. I'll check the eslint version though

Comment: Hi Peter, I checked the setting of the vscode extension and found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `getRouterFor()` method already has a declared type, the type will get inferred by typescript.
Can you try doing something like this:

```
public getRouter(this: BaseController) : Router {
 return UIComponent.getRouterFor(this) 
}
```

Comment: It is the same for any position of ": Router"